# Open another layout in a Fragment when click on listview item?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-fragments, listviewitem

In my Fragment, i have a Albums listView. I want to click on an item to open another layout and that new layout have a Song listView. So how can i call another layout by click on an item, and pass data to the new layout and set action for it. All i want to do just in a Fragment

Comment: "open another layout". DO you mean another activity or another fragment?

Comment: Please add the code for what you have done so far.

Comment: i hide a layout to open another, should i do thay way ?